# What commands does git use when communicating via ssh?

Tags: ssh, git, account-restrictions

Using `command=""` in `authorized_keys`, I can restrict the commands that can be run by a particular key.

What commands do I need to allow in order to have a functioning git remote?

From [the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) I can infer that `git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack` are required, but is there anything else?

Note I still want to be able to log into the user normally, just not with this key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Git includes a [`git-shell`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-shell.html) command suitable for use as a Git-only login shell. It accepts exactly the following commands:

> git receive-pack
>   git upload-pack
>   git upload-archive
>   git-receive-pack
>   git-upload-pack
>   git-upload-archive
>   cvs server (used for emulating a CVS server, and not required for the Git protocol)

So these are the only commands you need to allow. Every version of Git I have access to only uses the hyphenated versions.

`git-shell` itself may be good enough in itself for what you want to do, too.

---

You can verify what Git is running for any particular command by setting `GIT_SSH` to a shim that echoes the arguments. Make a script `ssh.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@" >&2
```

Then run:

```
GIT_SSH="./ssh.sh" git push
```

and you will see the remote command it tried to run.

Comment: So `command="git-shell" ssh-rsa ...` will work?

Comment: No, you'll want to list each of those commands above. `git-shell` is intended to be the login shell of a restricted git only user.

Comment: Be aware that if you are using git-lfs, it will use additional commands

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't want to use the user account for anything else you could just run `chsh` for the user and select `/usr/bin/git-shell` (or where it is located) as the login shell for the user.

However as you want to only restrict the user only when using a specific key, we need to create a helper script to do the same.

Create a file in for example the home directory (of the target host) called `git-ssh-remote-command`, containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec git-shell -c "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND"
```

Run `chmod a+rx /path/to/git-ssh-remote-command` to make it executable and then use it in your `.ssh/authorized_keys` file for the key you want to restrict to git-only access, for example:

```
restrict,command="/path/to/git-ssh-remote-command" ssh-dss 1478912c844...
```

With the help of the script, this will limit the key to execute only the commands allowed by git-shell.

**NOTE:** By default git-shell does not allow additional commands needed by e.g. git-lfs; see `man git-shell` for instructions how to do that if needed.